# Is it possible to force the browser to reload the same page with a hash?

Tags: javascript

I know I can add a hash to the end of the url like so:

```
window.location.hash = '#myFancyHash';
```

But for various reasons I need to fully reload the page. On some browsers this works fine:

```
window.location = window.location.href + '#myFancyHash';
```

But others refuse to reload the page since it sees the new url as just a hash version.

Is there any way to force all browsers to redirect (reload) the page anew?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
window.location.hash = '#myFancyHash';
window.location.reload()
```

This is cause a reload with the new hash

Comment: Sure this will work?

Comment: This doesn't work if the hash value is not modified (i.e. you reload expecting the browser to return to the same anchor). It will return to the previous *scroll position*.